# TPOT: classification fails on multi-class data

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, tpot

I cannot get TPot (v. 0.9.2, Python 2.7) working on multiclass data (although I could not find anything in the documentation of TPot saying it does only binary classification).

An example provided below. It runs until 9% and then drops dead with the error:

```
RuntimeError: There was an error in the TPOT optimization process. 
This could be because the data was not formatted properly, or because
data for a regression problem was provided to the TPOTClassifier 
object. Please make sure you passed the data to TPOT correctly.
```

But change n_classes to 2 and it is running okay.

```python
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score, make_scorer
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from tpot import TPOTClassifier

scorer = make_scorer(f1_score)
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=200, n_features=100,
                           n_informative=20, n_redundant=10,
                           n_classes=3, random_state=42)
tpot = TPOTClassifier(generations=10, population_size=20, verbosity=20, scoring=scorer)
tpot.fit(X, y)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, TPOT is supposed to work with multiclass data, too - the [example in the docs](https://epistasislab.github.io/tpot/using/#tpot-with-code) is with the MNIST dataset (10 classes).

The error is related to the `f1_score`; keeping your code with `n_classes=3`, and asking for

```python
tpot = TPOTClassifier(generations=10, population_size=20, verbosity=2)
```

(i.e. using the default `scoring='accuracy'`) works OK:

```
Warning: xgboost.XGBClassifier is not available and will not be used by TPOT.

Generation 1 - Current best internal CV score: 0.7447422496202984                                                                                
Generation 2 - Current best internal CV score: 0.7447422496202984                                                                                  
Generation 3 - Current best internal CV score: 0.7454927186634503                                                                                   
Generation 4 - Current best internal CV score: 0.7454927186634503             
Generation 5 - Current best internal CV score: 0.7706334316090413
Generation 6 - Current best internal CV score: 0.7706334316090413
Generation 7 - Current best internal CV score: 0.7706334316090413
Generation 8 - Current best internal CV score: 0.7706334316090413
Generation 9 - Current best internal CV score: 0.7757616367372464
Generation 10 - Current best internal CV score: 0.7808898418654516

Best pipeline: 

LogisticRegression(KNeighborsClassifier(DecisionTreeClassifier(input_matrix, criterion=entropy, max_depth=3, min_samples_leaf=15, min_samples_split=12), n_neighbors=6, p=2, weights=uniform), C=0.01, dual=False, penalty=l2)

TPOTClassifier(config_dict={'sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression': {'penalty': ['l1', 'l2'], 'C': [0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 0.5, 1.0, 5.0, 10.0, 15.0, 20.0, 25.0], 'dual': [True, False]}, 'sklearn.decomposition.PCA': {'iterated_power': range(1, 11), 'svd_solver': ['randomized']}, 'sklearn.feature_selection.Se...ocessing.PolynomialFeatures': {'degree': [2], 'interaction_only': [False], 'include_bias': [False]}},
        crossover_rate=0.1, cv=5, disable_update_check=False,
        early_stop=None, generations=10, max_eval_time_mins=5,
        max_time_mins=None, memory=None, mutation_rate=0.9, n_jobs=1,
        offspring_size=20, periodic_checkpoint_folder=None,
        population_size=20, random_state=None, scoring=None, subsample=1.0,
        verbosity=2, warm_start=False)
```

Asking for the F1 score with the usage [suggested in the docs](https://epistasislab.github.io/tpot/api/#classification), i.e.:

```python
tpot = TPOTClassifier(generations=10, population_size=20, verbosity=2, scoring='f1')
```

produces again the error you report, probably because the [default argument](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html) in `f1_score` is `average='binary'`, which indeed does not make sense for multi-class problems, and the simple `f1` is only for binary problems ([docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#common-cases-predefined-values)).

Using explicitly some other variation of F1 score in `scoring`, e.g. `f1_macro`, `f1_micro`, or `f1_weighted` works OK (not shown).

Comment: Thank you for a detailed answer! It was, indeed, the reason.

Comment: @galapah I told you ;) Seriously now, the fact that you indeed provided a [simple, minimal, and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) helped a lot in tracking down the cause - good job from your part, too